# Overlay a line function on a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid, relplot

My challenge is to overlay a custom line function graph over a scatter plot I already have, the code looks like follows:

```
base_beta = results.params
X_plot = np.linspace(0,1,400)

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, size = 6)
g = g.map(plt.scatter, "usable_area", "price", edgecolor="w")
```

Where `base_beta` is only a constant, and then one coefficient. Basically, I want to overlay a function that plots a line `y = constant + coefficient * x`

I tried to overlay a line using this but it did not work.

```
g = g.map_dataframe(plt.plot, X_plot, X_plot*base_beta[1]+base_beta[0], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

The current scatter plot looks like so:
[image]

Can any one help me with this?

--ATTEMPT 1

```
base_beta = results.params
X_plot = np.linspace(0,1,400)
Y_plot = base_beta [0] + base_beta[1]*X_plot

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, size = 6)
g = g.map(plt.scatter, "usable_area", "price", edgecolor="w")
plt.plot(X_plot, Y_plot, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Resulted in the same graph but no line:
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just call `plt.plot` to plot a line over the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['usable_area'] = 5*np.random.random(200)
data['price'] =  10*data['usable_area']+10*np.random.random(200)

X_plot = np.linspace(0, 7, 100)
Y_plot = 10*X_plot+5

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, height = 6)
g = g.map(plt.scatter, "usable_area", "price", edgecolor="w")
plt.plot(X_plot, Y_plot, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

- It is now recommended to use figure-level functions like [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) or [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) instead of directly using [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Sample Data and Imports

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a dataframe with sample x and y
np.random.seed(365)
x = 5*np.random.random(200)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': 10*x+10*np.random.random(200)})

# add custom line to the dataframe
base_beta = [10, 5]
df['y_line'] = base_beta[0] + base_beta[1]*df.x

display(df.head())
          x          y     y_line
0  4.707279  50.634968  33.536394
1  3.208014  33.890507  26.040068
2  3.423052  37.853276  27.115262
3  2.942810  29.899257  24.714052
4  2.719436  36.932170  23.597180
```

## Add Custom Line to Scatter Plot

### `sns.relplot` with [`.map`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map) or [`.map_dataframe`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe)

- Apply an axes-level plotting function (e.g. [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot)) to each facet of the figure-level plot.
- [seaborn: Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)

```py
ax = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', data=df, height=3.5, aspect=1.5)
ax.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y_line', color='g')
```

[image]

### [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) with `sns.lineplot`

- Plot two axes-level plots to the same figure.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
p1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', ax=ax)
p2 = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y_line', color='g', ax=ax)
```

[image]

---

## Regression Line to a Scatter Plot

- For a regression line

  - Use [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) for figure-level regression plot
  - Use [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) for an axes-level regression plot.

### `sns.lmplot`

```py
g = sns.lmplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', line_kws={'color': 'g'}, height=3.5, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

### `sns.regplot`

```py
ax = sns.regplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', line_kws={'color': 'g'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also overlay a Seaborn plot over the data, given you have the points that make up that line (below, I call them `x_pred` and `y_pred`):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 8.5))
sns.scatterplot(x='M2NS_PC1', y='FII5', data=ir_ms, ax=ax)
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k', linewidth=1)  # added because i want the origin
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k', linewidth=1)

fitted = sm.ols(formula='FII5 ~ M2NS_PC1', data=ir_ms).fit(cov_type='HC3')

x = ir_ms['M2NS_PC1']
x_pred = np.linspace(x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1, 50)
y_pred = fitted.predict(exog=dict(M2NS_PC1=x_pred))

sns.lineplot(x=x_pred, y=y_pred, ax=ax)
```

Then, just plot it all on the same axis.

[image]