# how to add a matplotlib plot to a multiple seaborn plot

Tags: matplotlib, regression, seaborn, lmplot

i plot a multiple plot using seabor lmplot and i want to add a x=y line to this plot, can you help me to solve this problem?

my code :

```
sns.set_theme(style="white")
sns.lmplot(data=data, x='Target',y='Predicted', hue="Type",col='Model', height=5,legend=False, palette=dict(Train="g", Test="m"))
plt.plot([data.iloc[:,0].min(), data.iloc[:,0].max()], [data.iloc[:,0].min(), data.iloc[:,0].max()], "--", label="Perfect model")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

and my output:
[image]

i plot a multiple plot using seabor lmplot and i want to add a x=y line to this plot, can you help me to solve this problem?

my code :

```
sns.set_theme(style="white")
sns.lmplot(data=data, x='Target',y='Predicted', hue="Type",col='Model', height=5,legend=False, palette=dict(Train="g", Test="m"))
plt.plot([data.iloc[:,0].min(), data.iloc[:,0].max()], [data.iloc[:,0].min(), data.iloc[:,0].max()], "--", label="Perfect model")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

and my output:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64535637/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46598371/7758804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plt.plot()` that you are using will only add line to the last plot. Do add the line to each line, you will need to use the axes for the `lmplot()` and plot a line for each of the subplots. As I don't have your data, used the standard penguins dataset to show this. Hope this helps...

```
data = sns.load_dataset('penguins') ## My data
sns.set_theme(style="white")

g=sns.lmplot(data=data, x='bill_length_mm',y='bill_depth_mm', hue="species", col="sex", height=5,legend=False, palette=dict(Adelie="g", Chinstrap="m", Gentoo='orange'))

axes = g.fig.axes ## Get the axes for all the subplots
for ax in axes: ## For each subplot, draw the line
    ax.plot([data.iloc[:,2].min(), data.iloc[:,2].max()], [data.iloc[:,3].min(), data.iloc[:,3].max()], "--", label="Perfect model")

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]